# Question about associated primes (Eisenbud Theorem 3.1)

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm studying the proof of Theorem 3.1(c) of Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to prove the underlined statement. But I'm not sure certainly it is.

My attempt is :
Let $r+P  \in \ker f$ . First, note that by the above proposition 2.10, $ \varphi =  u^{-1}f$  means that the
$\varphi$ is of the form $1/u \otimes_{R} f$ (Is it true?). So, second, note that

\begin{align}   \notag
    \varphi(u/1\otimes_{R}(r+P)) &= (1/u \otimes_{R} f) (u/1 \otimes (r+P)) \\  \notag
      &= ((1/u) \cdot (u/1)) \otimes_{R} f(r+P) \\ \notag
      &= 1 \otimes_{R} 0 = 0 \ (\in R[U^{-1}]\otimes_{R}M \cong M[U^{-1}] ) \\  \notag
   \end{align}

So, $u/1 \otimes_{R} (r+P) \in \ker\varphi$ ; i.e. upto $R[U^{-1}] \otimes_{R} R/P \cong R/P[U^{-1}]$, we have that $u \cdot(r+P)/1 = (ur+P)/1 = (0+P)/1 $ since $\varphi$ is injective.

So, there exits $ e \in U$ such that $ e \cdot(ur+P) = 0 $ so that $(eu +P) (r+P)) = 0 $.

Now, since $eu \in U$ and $P\cap U = \varnothing$ and $R/P$ is integral domain, $eu+P$ is nonzero divisor in  $R/P$ and $r+P =0 $. So $f$ is injective.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Actually, I think it should be much more easier, Eisenbud define $\phi_p(r/u)=\phi (r)/u$. So the consequence almost follows directly.